# Prism Navigation

Tags: wpf, prism

I've started my first tryout with Prism and that's what I've done yet:

@Bootstrapper.cs

```
ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
catalog.AddModule(typeof(ExampleModule));
```

@ExampleModule.cs

```
public void Initialize()
        {
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TopBarRegion", typeof(StandardTopBar));
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("CenterRegion", typeof(PersonStammdatenControl));
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("BottomBarRegion", typeof(Bottombar));
        }
```

StandardTopbar is a own ClassProject with UserControland has a menue. I would like to inject a view in CenterRegion with a command at menueitem, but I don't really know how. Does I also have to declare Topbar as a module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple approach:

@Module:

```
protected override void RegierTypes()
    {
    base.Container.RegisterType<IMainPageViewModel, MainPageViewModel>();
    var viewModel = container.Resolve<IMainPageViewModel>();
    RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ContentRegion].Add(viewModel.View);
}
```

---

@ViewModel:

```
private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private readonly IMainPage view;

public MainPageViewModel(IMainPage view, 
IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base(view)
    {
    this.view = view;
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
}
```

---

```
public interface IMainPage : IView
    {

    }
```

---

```
public interface IView
{
    IViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    IView View { get; set; }
}
```

---

@bootstrapper:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(MainModule));

        return catalog;
    }
```